# Unable to send any HTML elements other than <h1> as a function response to HTTPS request using node.js (Express)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, https

If I change "< h1 >" to any other HTML tag such as "< h2 > or < p >" it fails to render them. I have no idea what's wrong.

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

// home page
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  const queryCity = "London";
  // const queryCity = String(req.body.cityName);
  const apiKey = "lorem";
  const url =
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
    queryCity +
    "&appid=" +
    apiKey +
    "&units=metric";

  https.get(url, function (response) {
    response.on("data", function (data) {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);

      const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
      const feel = weatherData.main.feels_like;
      const weatherIcon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
      const iconUrl =
        "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + weatherIcon + "@2x.png";

      res.write(
        "<h1>Temperature in " + queryCity + " is " + temp + "deg Celsius.</h1>"
      );
      res.write("It feels like " + feel + "deg Celsius.");
      res.write("<img src=" + iconUrl + ">");
      res.send(); // there can only be one res.send()
    });
  });
});

// server port
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server live on port 3000");
});
```

[this is what happens when I change h1 to h2 or p. Img tag fails too. What am I doing wrong here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp2zT.png)

Comment: Don't use `res.write`. Instead. Build ur HTML in a string and then call `res.send(htmlstr)` and it will send html. Further it would be good if you use somekind of `view engine` if rendering big html chunks

Comment: Use res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html') before sending the response.

Answer (score 0):

This code never fail:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.type('text/html');
  res.send('<h1>I am html</h1>');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Try to test your html generation with this basic code to be sure that error is not a nodejs issue.

Another tips:

- replace `res.write` to `res.send` like my example
- don't call `res.write` several times, just one time sending a string previously created with your html lines
- add content type text/html to your response

Answer (score 0):

Had this error as well earlier. Was able to fix it by adding an html tag on the first `res.write`.

Using your code, it would be like this;

```
res.write(
    "<html><h1>Temperature in " + queryCity + " is " + temp + "deg Celsius.</h1></html>"
  );
```